# Mouse clicks only 50% of the time

Tags: mouse

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and everything seems fine, except the mouse clicks only work half the time. I often have to click things (whatever it is) several times before any response and it's driving me crazy. The mouse works fine in Windows XP. It also sometimes freezes at login screen.

Computer: Asus
CPU: AMD Sempron(tm) Processor 3400+
Graphics: Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430
Mouse: Trust MI-2540D

I'm new to Linux so I don't know how to get all the data you might want, sorry about that, but tell me how and you shall have it.

Comment: I had that issue too, but then I upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Beta 1, and I no longer that that issue.

Comment: intresting. is the beta stable enough?

Comment: The *alpha* has been stable for me... I upgraded to the beta and it seems fine too.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the VGA drivers for the Nvidia GeForce 6150SE nForce 430?, If not do so, If it is yes, then try without effects, (Look for Accessible settings, may be you have accidentally turn something on)

Comment: Ive tried the drivers: nvidia version current and nvidia 173. No change. Ive also tried running with no effects without change. Ive also tried xfc4 to see if it was a gnome issue. but no change.
The problem was there right from a fresh ubuntu install so I doubt its anything Ive turned on.

Comment: Have you tried the 10.10 version? If yes, does it also has the same problem? try this in 11.10 terminal                   /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test-p  This will display some info about your graphics, such as blacklisted, software rendered and unity 3d support. (Thanks to the Full circle group-Ubuntu 11.10 and Unity special edition)

Comment: Heres what I get from the support_test : 

OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW!
OpenGL version string:  2.1.2 NVIDIA 173.14.30

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes

I have not tried 10.10.

thank you for your help sofar.

Comment: It seems that almost everything supports your hardware (Next time use a sreenshot, copy pasting terminal is unreadable) no idea about this from here! because I had the same problem and it ended after The vga drivers, If you could visit Ubuntu hardware compatible site and check your hardware there, and confirm that it really works, It'll be useful, :-)